# SQL Server / T-SQL : How to update equal percentages of a resultset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a way to take a resultset of KeyIDs and divide it up as equally as possible and update records differently for each division based on the KeyIDs.  In other words, there is

```
SELECT KeyID
FROM   TableA
WHERE (some criteria exists)
```

I want to update TableA 3 different ways by 3 equal portions of KeyIDs.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value1
WHERE  KeyID IN (the first 1/3 of the SELECT resultset above)

UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value2
WHERE  KeyID IN (the second 1/3 of the SELECT resultset above)

UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value3
WHERE  KeyID IN (the third 1/3 of the SELECT resultset above)
```

or something to that effect.  Thanks for any and all of your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With TiledItems As
    (
        Select KeyId
            , NTILE(3) OVER( ORDER BY ... ) As NTileNum
        From TableA
        Where ...
    )
Update TableA
Set FieldA = Case TI.NTileNum
                    When 1 Then Value1
                    When 2 Then Value2
                    When 3 Then Value3
                    End
From TableA As A
    Join TiledItems As TI
        On TI.KeyId = A.KeyId
```

Comment: Perfect!  Brillian!!  Just what I needed!  Thanks to everyone who answered, especially Martin and Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I haven't got time to knock up a complete solution but the gist of one would be to use a CTE with the NTILE function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx to divide into 3 groups then join onto that CTE in your UPDATE statement and do a CASE statement against the NTILE group to determine whether to use Value1, Value2, or Value3.

**Edit**
See [Thomas's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804694/sql-server-t-sql-how-to-update-equal-percentages-of-a-resultset/2805328#2805328) answer for the code for this as looks like he had the same idea!

Answer (score 1):

For a simple distribution, create a random ranking and modulo by 3...

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
    FieldA =
        CASE Ranking % 3
           WHEN 1 THEN B.Value1
           WHEN 2 THEN B.Value2
           WHEN 0 THEN B.Value3
        END
FROM
    TableA A
    inner join
    (SELECT
        ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID /*or something*/) AS Ranking,
        Value1, Value2, Value3
    FROM
        TableA
    ) B on A.ID = B.ID
where (some criteria exists)
```

You can change the ORDER BY for the ROW_NUMBER(), or use NTILE and remove the modulo

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are evenly-distributed, then you could use the modulus (`%`) operator to select out unique thirds of the result set.

```
update TableA set FieldA = Value1 where KeyID % 3 = 0;
update TableA set FieldA = Value2 where KeyID % 3 = 1;
update TableA set FieldA = Value3 where KeyID % 3 = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting what you say literally, you could number the rows in the returned row set, and then select the different segements based on their row number.

E.g.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value1
WHERE  KeyID IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT <your rows>, ROW_NUMBER() (ORDER BY <anyRow>) AS RowNumber FROM <yourTable> ) base
WHERE RowNumber<Count(RowNumber)/3)

UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value1
WHERE  KeyID IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT <your rows>, ROW_NUMBER() (ORDER BY <anyRow>) AS RowNumber FROM <yourTable> ) base
WHERE RowNumber<Count(RowNumber)*2/3 && RowNumber>=Count(RowNumber)/3)

UPDATE TableA
SET    FieldA = Value1
WHERE  KeyID IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT <your rows>, ROW_NUMBER() (ORDER BY <anyRow>) AS RowNumber FROM <yourTable> ) base
WHERE owNumber>=Count(RowNumber)*2/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Query (OtherKeyID, PCT)
AS
(
SELECT  KeyID, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyID)) / foo.CNT AS PCT 
FROM    TableA 
JOIN    (SELECT CONVERT(float, COUNT(1)) AS CNT FROM TableA) foo ON 1 = 1 
WHERE   (criteria)
)

UPDATE TableA  
SET    FieldA = (CASE
    WHEN PCT < .3333 THEN Value1 
    WHEN PCT BETWEEN .3333 and .6666 THEN Value2
    WHEN PCT > .6666 THEN Value3 ELSE NULL END)
FROM   Query 
WHERE  KeyID = OtherKeyID AND PCT < .3333
```

Note that you can alter the `ORDER BY` clause in the query to any valid expression, which will allow you to define your "first third" by any criteria.